# Plotting and labeling each bin in a histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataset that contains categories (labels) of different emotions. You can see which categories from the "labels" variable defined in the code below. Each of these categories has a different amount of data available in this dataset, and I'm trying to represent the distribution of the dataset through histogram bins.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#labels inside emo variable, however they are labeled with numbers from 0 to 6 in sequence according to labels variable
labels = ['angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise','neutral']
labels_np = np.array(labels)
#df_training is holding the train_set.csv, where I am selecting a single column which is 'emotion' 
emo = df_training["emotion"].hist()
plt.plot(labels_np,emo)
```

**df_training['emotion']:**

[image: df_training]

This is what I'm getting as an error:

```
**ValueError:** x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1,)
```

**This is the desired output:**

[image: Histogram]

Comment: It is hard for people to help you unless you provide them with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As for code part, I have given everything that I have, I will just try to explain the variables maybe what they are, as for what I want to achieve I think I have described everything need, including the image.

Comment: You need to give `df_training`

Comment: Hopefully its clearer now, I have commented in the code

Comment: As you can see these bins, normally if I wouldnt include **labels_np**  in the plot I would get these bins labeled starting from 0 which is angry till 6 which is neutral, and I am trying to name them as in picture using the approach above!

Comment: One important problem is that `emo = df_training.hist` makes emo a [list of `AxesSubplot`s](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), which is not the data of a histogram. You might want to use [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: Please provide a sample for `df_training` this is not reproducible.

Comment: I will edit the question and provide you with df_training image of what it consists of so you have a better idea

Comment: I just edited the code a little, I removed the ravel() as I am accessing exclusively only df_training['emotion'] now, as it is doing the same thing as ravel. Now you can see what the df_training holds. Each number from 0 to 6 represents one category, I have explained it above also, for example 0 == angry, 1 == disgust, etc. @Sheldore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to draw the histogram and set the correct labels.
`df_training.hist` already draws a histogram, but with 0,1,2,... as x-labels.
You can change that with calling `plt.xticks`. As the center of the bars is at positions, 0.5,1.5,2.5,... putting the ticks there gets everything aligned.

As your data only contains values from 0 to 6, it is best to have just 7 bins, so 8 boundaries, `hist` can be called `bins=range(8)`. Default `bins=10`, what is definitely not what you want.

In the code below I removed the x-grid lines as they are disturbing and not really needed. The edgecolor is set `ec='white'` to better distinguish the bars. The 'emotion' column of df_training is filled with some random data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

labels = ['angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise','neutral']
df_training = pd.DataFrame( {'emotion': np.random.randint(0, 7, 100)})
emo = df_training.hist(column='emotion', ec='white', bins=range(8))
plt.grid(False, axis='x')
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(0.5,6.6,1), labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot]